# Difference between Qt Strings Functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qlineedit

I made a project on *VS2005* using *Qt -4.7.4* version. In that project i used lineEdit and took the text from lineEdit like this

```
const char* test= lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str();
```

The above line worked perfectly but now i am using VS2010 and using the same above line but it is not showing me anything for the `test` variable.

```
qDebug()<<lineEdit->text()<<endl;
```

The above line is printing the right value of lineEdit but when i am using the `std::string` and then using `cout`. it is not showing any value on *VS2010*. So then i used

```
const char* test= lineEdit->text().toLatin1().data();
```

this above line is now showing me everything perfectly on *VS2010*.

I have no idea why `const char* test= lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str();` is working perfectly on *VS2005* and why not on *VS2010*.

Comment: When in Qt land, use Qt classes and functions. I would really avoid changing to Standard C++ classes if you're not writing an external interface, and even then I would prefer to stick to the Qt side of things.

Comment: Actually i am writing an external interface...i am using this lineEdit value in mongoDB..which works with const char*.

Comment: What encoding does it expect? `QString` is Unicode, so this matters.

Answer (score 2):

From [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toStdString)

> This operator (QString::toStdString()) is only available if Qt is configured with STL compatibility enabled.

So I guess there is some configuration issue between *VS2005* and *VS2010*.

**As a side note:**

You should not take the pointer returned by `c_str()`and use it. If the `QString` is changed or goes *out of scope*, so is the `std::string` returned by `QString::toStdString()`, and the pointer is *invalidated*. If you use that pointer somewhere else by copying it, you will have undefined behavior. Better make a `std::string`/`QString` object from the `text()` property and then use it.

Comment: actually I think the `c_str` is only valid as long as the stdstring is valid, so as soon as it is destroyed (at the semicolon) the c_str is no longer valid

Comment: @ratchetfreak, yes. after the semicolon the `QString` goes out of scope, so does the `char*`. I guess I mentioned it.

Comment: @RakibulHasan what you pointed is a real defect. Our app produced garbage logs because of this. Same goes for `lineEdit->text().toLatin1().data()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong! This works in one case just by luck.

Temporary objects are involved here. In chain `lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str()` you have temporary objects: `QString`, `std::string`.
Now last temporary objects gives you pointer to c-string and this object is **owner** of this c-string. Before next line temporary object is destroyed and you c-string also is freed.

it worked in VS2005 by pure luck. Code is incorrect.

This chain works only if value is used in this single line. So this lines are are correct:

```
qDebug() << lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str();
someFinction(lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str());
```

Another way to fix it:

```
std::string s = lineEdit->text().toStdString();
qDebug() << s.c_str();
someFunction(s.c_str());
```

C-string will live as long as `std::string`

Comment: in that second line in the example the passed pointer is only valid inside the function, if it stores it for later access you get undefined behavior.

Comment: this is obvious when I'm explaining the problem.

Comment: Dear Sir, I already mentioned in the question that even `std::cout` is not working like this..`std::cout<<lineEdit->text().toStdString();` . I already tried your way but was getting some garbage value.

Comment: and regarding `qDebug()`, it worked because it is printing QString value directly without any conversion to `std::string` and `c_str`.

Comment: I recommend to improve question than include code with `std::cout`. Remember to include exact contents of `QString` and what you get on console. I'm suspecting that you have funny characters which are get lost during conversion (probably you get bunch of question marks or squares). This might be text codec related issue.

Comment: @MarekR..yeah you are right, when I am doing `std::cout<<lineEdit->text().toStdString()`, it is not showing anything but when i m doing `std::cout<<lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str`, it is showing the text but with additional funny characters. but if am copying the lineEdit text first into `const char* temp` like this `temp= lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str()` it is showing nothing...any recommendations now?

Comment: one more point when i am doing only `std::cout<<lineEdit->text().toStdString()` a stream of funny characters starts displaying on console and then runtime error pops out.

Comment: again update your question with exact code you use and exact data you have on input and output. If you do that I'm sure someone will solve your problem. Also you command indicate that you still don't understand my answer. `temp= lineEdit->text().toStdString().c_str()` is wrong, it works just by pure luck!